# Does my ViewModel have a property of the Model and individual properties?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a Model with the following properties:

```
public class Authorization : BindableBase
{                 
    public int id {get; set;}

    public string member {get; set;}

    public DateTime startDate {get; set;}
}
```

Now on my `View Model` I need to have the same(*ish*) properties for the `View`.

Does that mean I should also have a property on my `View Model` of my `Model`:

```
public Authorization auth {get; set;};
```

Then a "mapping" method to push/pull data between the `View Model` properties and the `Model` property's properties?

Caliburn.Micro doesn't seem to be able to Bind to properties of a property so I don't see a way around this.

Am I on the right track, is there a simpler or better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you commented:

> Pull down my Model property, call method to assign values to ViewModel
>   properties, through binding make changes at UI that are reflected back
>   to ViewModel properties, on Save call method to assign ViewModel
>   properties back to the properties of the Model property and save to my
>   DB passing the Model property from my View Model

sounds reasonable - but as far as I recall, CM can bind to properties of a property (you can also explicitly bind failing that)

You just need to use underscore _ to separate your binding path for the `Name` of the control

e.g.

```
<Button x:Name="SomeObject_SomeProperty" />
```

Now I've never tried it but this code in `ViewModelBinder` CM source seems to suggest it would work:

```
var cleanName = element.Name.Trim('_');
var parts = cleanName.Split(new[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var property = viewModelType.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(parts[0]);
var interpretedViewModelType = viewModelType;

for (int i = 1; i < parts.Length && property != null; i++) 
{
    interpretedViewModelType = property.PropertyType;
    property = interpretedViewModelType.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(parts[i]);
}

...etc
```

If you do need to manually map then AutoMapper is a great lib to use - you can reshape data in the mappings which is a good way of getting model data into a ViewModel which may not necessarily reflect the shape of the model

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion sounds reasonable, but your example code is currently not notifying so you will not be able to use binding. Simply deriving from `BindableBase` isn't enough, you need to call whatever method in `BindableBase` fires `NotifyPropertyChanged` in your property setters.

Check out [this for an example viewmodel class in caliburn.micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration,%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation)

Use your `View Model` to provide bindable properties representing the `Model` data you wish to use in your GUI. Write code to update your `View Model` properties with the respective `Model` property values and in the `View Model` property setters you can update your model via your `auth` property.

Comment: Yes, thank you about BindableBase and INPC.  I am actually using them I just cut it out for simplicity's sake in my post.  Maybe a mistake...  Anyway, would a rough order of operations go like this: Pull down my Model property, call method to assign values to ViewModel properties, through binding make changes at UI that are reflected back to ViewModel properties, on Save call method to assign ViewModel properties back to the properties of the Model property and save to my DB passing the Model property from my View Model.

Comment: That sounds good to me, this way you have managed to abstract your view from your database via a ViewModel; your View only knows about your ViewModel and your ViewModel has a reference to your Model.